# Prove that if a function is bounded by $M\in\mathbb{R}$ then its limit is also bounded by $M$

Tags: limits, analysis, proof-writing, solution-verification

Let $A \ne \emptyset$ be a set, let $x_0$ be a limit point for $A$ and let $f:A \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function bounded by $M\in\mathbb{R}$ (that is there exists $M\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $-M \leq f(x) \leq M$).

Suppose that there exists and it is finite the limit
$$\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x)=l$$
Then as well
$$-M \leq l \leq M$$

My attempt: since by hypothesis the limit $l$ of $f$ as $x\to x_0$ exists then it is true that for all $\epsilon>0$ exists $\delta_{\epsilon}>0$ such that $0<|x-x_0|<\delta_{\epsilon} \implies |f(x)-l|<\epsilon$; this is equivalent to $l-\epsilon<f(x)<l+\epsilon$.

This means that it is $f(x)>l-\epsilon$, and then by hypothesis of boundedness of $f$ it is $M \geq f(x)>l-\epsilon \implies M > l-\varepsilon$ and it is $l+\epsilon > f(x) \geq -M \implies l+\epsilon > -M$; since $\epsilon>0$ is arbitrary, this means $l \leq M$ and $-M \leq l$, that is $-M \leq l \leq M$.

Is this correct? I have another question too: in all this context I have *both* $f(x) \leq M$ and $f(x) \leq l+\epsilon$, so when I say that $f(x) \leq M$ to conclude the proof how do I know that it is $M \leq l+\epsilon$? Similarly for $f(x) \geq -M$ and $f(x) \geq l-\epsilon$. I don't get how I can use recklessly this inequalities when I don't know which one of the two is verified. Thank you.

Comment: everything looks fine in your proof. in regards to your question at the bottom, you don’t necessarily require $M\leq l+\epsilon$.

Comment: @CSquared: Thanks for your comment, maybe I see it now: it doesn't matter if it is $M \leq l+\epsilon$ or $l+\epsilon \leq M$ because in both cases we have $f(x) \leq l+\epsilon \leq M \implies f(x) \leq M$ or $f(x) \leq M \leq l+\epsilon \implies f(x) \leq M$ and this is all that matter for the proof because I will still get the inequality I need in both cases $M \leq l+\epsilon$ or $l+\epsilon \leq M$ (and it goes the same for the other inequality).

Comment: that’s correct!